# Iterate through a dictionary with subelements in Ansible

Tags: dictionary, ansible

I have to create a list based on a dictionary.
To get the element from the dictionary, I need to join "the server" + "the domain". The problem is that I have 3 different domains.
At the moment, I'm repeating the code to be able to use the 3 different domains.

```
- name: "Get server instances {{ ansible_fqdn }}"
  set_fact:
    app_ps_mon_list: "{{ app_ps_mon_list | default ([]) + [ app_instance ] }}"
  vars:
    app_instance: |
      [Java,<event_type>]
      java    critical 1-
      *ARGS {{item.value.INSTANCE_NAME.split("/")[1]}}
  with_dict: '{{ server_instances[ansible_hostname + "<DOMAIN1>"] }}'
  when:  '{{server_instances[ansible_hostname + "<DOMAIN1>"] is defined and item.key != "SERVER_IMPACT"}}'

- name: "Get server instances {{ ansible_fqdn }}"
  set_fact:
    app_ps_mon_list: "{{ app_ps_mon_list | default ([]) + [ app_instance ] }}"
  vars:
    app_instance: |
      [Java,<event_type>]
      java    critical 1-
      *ARGS {{item.value.INSTANCE_NAME.split("/")[1]}}
  with_dict: '{{ server_instances[ansible_hostname + "<DOMAIN2>"] }}'
  when:  '{{server_instances[ansible_hostname + "<DOMAIN2>"] is defined and item.key != "SERVER_IMPACT"}}'

- name: "Get server instances {{ ansible_fqdn }}"
  set_fact:
    app_ps_mon_list: "{{ app_ps_mon_list | default ([]) + [ app_instance ] }}"
  vars:
    app_instance: |
      [Java,<event_type>]
      java    critical 1-
      *ARGS {{item.value.INSTANCE_NAME.split("/")[1]}}
  with_dict: '{{ server_instances[ansible_hostname + "<DOMAIN3>"] }}'
  when:  '{{server_instances[ansible_hostname + "<DOMAIN3>"] is defined and item.key != "SERVER_IMPACT"}}'
```

I've been trying to do the same with_subelements without success. Also I tried to use "ansible_fqdn", but the fqdn domain usually don't match the actual domain (I know its a mess).

Is there any workaround I could use to avoid repeating the code?

**UPDATE**

The idea of the playbook is to obtain the solutions from the server I'm using as host (ansible_hostname varaible).
Once it get the solutions, create a list using some information from the  INSTANCE_NAME

This is a generic version of the dictionary:

```
{
  "<server_name><domain>": {
    "<solution_id>": {
      "INSTANCE_NAME": "",
      "SOLUTION_CATEGORY": "",
      "SOLUTION_NAME": ""
    },
    "<solution_id>": {
      "INSTANCE_NAME": "",
      "SOLUTION_CATEGORY": "",
      "SOLUTION_NAME": ""
    },
    SERVER_IMPACT: "",
  ...,

}
```

This is how the list should look like (its a multiline string variable, dumb but useful):

```
[
  [Java]
  java    critical 1-
  *ARGS <iINSTANCE_NAME info>
], 
[
  [Java]
  java    critical 1-
  *ARGS  <iINSTANCE_NAME info>
]
```

Comment: Can you give us an example of the dictionary you're starting with (input) and the list you want (output)?

Comment: I have added some generic info, the dictionary structure and the list